# How to hide a select tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this simple form:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" >
<table>

<tr>
<td>
Sex:
</td>
<td>
  <select name="sex" >
   <option value="e">Select  </option>
   <option value="girl">Girl  </option>
   <option value="boy">Boy  </option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
Accessories:
</td>
<td>
  <select name="earrings" >
   <option value="e">Select  </option>
   <option value="gold">gold  </option>
   <option value="silver">silver  </option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>


</table>

<br>
<input type="submit" size="10" value="Go" name="go">
</form>
```

and I want that when I click on "boy" in the first select then this block have to dissapears:

```
<tr>
<td>
Accessories:
</td>
<td>
  <select name="earrings" >
   <option value="e">Select  </option>
   <option value="gold">gold  </option>
   <option value="silver">silver  </option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

I can do this with CSS ?
If not, I can do this with javascript ?

Comment: CSS, no; JavaScript, yes. Does it need to be vanilla JavaScript, or would you be amenable to using a library (such as jQuery, MooTools, Prototype, Scriptaculous, Glow..)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't do this in CSS, but you can in JavaScript

```
function hide(){
var earrings = document.getElementById('earringstd');
earrings.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function show(){
var earrings = document.getElementById('earringstd');
earrings.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Just make sure that your `td` has `id=earringstd`

Then create function:

```
function genderSelectHandler(select){
if(select.value == 'girl'){
show();
}else if(select.value == 'boy'){
hide();
}}
```

Now all you have to is change your gender select tag to:

```
<select name="sex" onchange="genderSelectHandler(this)">
```

Comment: clumsy, `gender.form.earring.style.visibility = 'hidden'` does the job

Comment: There's probably a syntax error or some in my code, I've typed it from the top of my head

Comment: My bad! It should be `onchange` not `onselect`. Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

The hidden property hides the select but the tag is still rendered, and takes up space on the page.

If you want to hide a select and not want it to appear at all, but still be able to interact with the DOM, here's some sample code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">

        function hide(){
          var elem = document.getElementById('sel1');
          elem.style.display = 'none';
        }

        function show(){
          var elem = document.getElementById('sel1');
          elem.style.display = 'inline';
        }

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

      <select id='sel1' style='display:inline;'/>

      <input type="button" onclick="show();" value="Show"></input><br>
      <input type="button" onclick="hide();" value="Hide"></input><br>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old but I altered Goran code as listed below and thought I would share.  This collapses the code so that it doesn't retain it's space on the page, whereas the code listed above holds continues to hold it's form but becomes invisible.

```
function genderSelectHandler(select){
if(select.value == 'girl'){
$("#earringstd").show() 
}else{
$("#earringstd").hide();
}}

<select name="sex" onchange="genderSelectHandler(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done using just CSS in browsers that support the `:has` operator.

```
tr:has(select[name="sex"] option:checked:not([value="girl"])) + tr {
    display: none;
}
```

This selector in the code above finds any `<tr>` with a `<select name="sex">` descendant, where the option currently selected isn't girl, and hides the adjacent `<tr>`.